# Calculating PowerShell ticks in Bash

Tags: bash, powershell, datetime

I am translating a PowerShell script in Bash.

This is how the [ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0) for current datetime are obtained in PowerShell:

```
[System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks;
```

By following the [definition of Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0), this is how I am trying to approximate the same calculation using the `date` command in bash:

```
echo $(($(($(date -u '+%s') - $(date -d "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000 UTC" '+%s'))) * 10000000 ))
```

This is what I got the last time I tried:

```
$ echo $(($(($(date -u '+%s') - $(date -d "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000 UTC" '+%s'))) * 10000000 )) ; pwsh -c "[System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks;"
637707117310000000
637707189324310740
```

In particular, the first 7 digits are identical, but digits in position 8 and 9 are still too different between the two values.

I calculated that this means there is just a 2 hours difference between the 2 values. But why? It cannot be the timezone, since I specified UTC timezone in both `date` commands, right? What do you think?

**Note:** my suspects about the timezone are increasing, since I am currently based in UTC+2 (therefore 2 hours difference from UTC), but how is this possible since I explicitly specified UTC as timezone in the `date` commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it! The problem wasn't in the `date` commands, it was in the PowerShell command, which was using the +2 Timezone (CEST time). To fix this, I am now using `UtcNow` instead of `Now`.

This is what I am getting now:

```
$ echo $(($(($(date -u '+%s') - $(date -d "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000 UTC" '+%s'))) * 10000000 )) ; pwsh -c "[System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Ticks;"
637707132410000000
637707132415874110
```

As you can see, now all the digits are identical, except for the last 7th digits, since I added zeros on purpose to convert from seconds to ticks, as I am not interested in fractions of seconds (for now) and I  consider them negligible.

### Alternative way

Another way to make the two values identical (still excluding fractions of seconds), is to remove the `-u` option in the first `date` command in order to use the current time zone, and replace `UTC` with `+0200` in the second `date` command. If I do this, I can leave `Now` on the PowerShell command (instead of replacing it with `UtcNow`).

By doing this, I am getting:

```
$ echo $(($(($(date '+%s') - $(date -d "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000 +0200" '+%s'))) * 10000000)) ; pwsh -c "[System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks;"
637707218060000000
637707218067248090
```

### If you also want fractions of seconds

I just understood that if you also need to consider fractions of seconds, then you just need to add the result of `date '+%N'` (nanoseconds) divided by 100 to the calculation, in any of the two approaches shown above.

Since the result of `date '+%N'` can have some leading zeros, Bash may think it's an octal value. To avoid this, just prepend `10#` to explicitly say it is a decimal value.

For example, taking the second approach shown above (the "alternative way"), now I get:

```
$ echo $(($(($(date '+%s') - $(date -d "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000 +0200" '+%s'))) * 10000000 + $((10#$(date '+%N')/100)) ))
637707225953311420
```